# The component styled.p with the id of "sc-iseJRi" has been created dynamically

Tags: reactjs, components, styled-components, compiler-warnings, flux

Good evening everyone, I need some help.
I can't solve a warning:

> Keyframes.js:20 The component styled.p with the id of "sc-iseJRi" has
> been created dynamically. You may see this warning because you've
> called styled inside another component. To resolve this only create
> new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function
> component.

In this link ( https://pastebin.com/a0kMztfD ) is an example of how I use the styled-component.
In a checkboxes file I have all the functions I use for the styled-component rules, which I then call in the App.js file to assign them to a const variable to use in the return()
How could I solve this problem? It doesn't create any errors for me but of course it creates a thousand warnings.

I also put the code in addition to the link put previously:

**In cards.js**:

```
export function getCard(Card) {
 
    let fillMode = (Card.style === null) ? 'both' : Card.style.fillMode
    let duration = (Card.style === null) ? '1s' : Card.style.duration
 
    const tmp = keyframes`
 
                      from,to {
                                    width: ${Card.width};
                                    height: ${Card.height};
                                    background-color: ${Card.colorCard};
                                    background: linear-gradient(${Card.colorCard2}, ${Card.colorCard});
                                    box-shadow: 0 16px 16px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
                                    border-radius: 6px;
                                    overflow: hidden;
                                    position: relative;
                                    margin: ${Card.marginCard}; 
                      }
    `;
 
    const CardFinal = styled.div`
          animation: ${duration} ${tmp} ${fillMode};
    `;
 
    return CardFinal
}
```

**In App.js**:

```
Const CardContainer = getCard(card1)
 
return (
    <CardContainer></CardContainer>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a `styled.div` inside your `getCard` function.

The way you get rid of this warning is to move the creation of `CardFinal` outside of getCard and use `getCard` function to return whatever css you want to generate and pass them as props later on. [Here's how you can pass props with styled-components.](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

This is how it would look like for your code

```
const CardFinal = styled.div`
  ${getAnimation}
`;

export function getCardProps(Card) {
  const fillMode = Card.style === null ? "both" : Card.style.fillMode;
  const duration = Card.style === null ? "1s" : Card.style.duration;

  const tmp = keyframes`
    from,to {
      width: ${Card.width};
      height: ${Card.height};
      background-color: ${Card.colorCard};
      background: linear-gradient(${Card.colorCard2}, ${Card.colorCard});
      box-shadow: 0 16px 16px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      border-radius: 6px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      margin: ${Card.marginCard}; 
    }
  `;

  return { fillMode, duration, tmp };
}

const getAnimation = ({ duration, tmp, fillMode }) => {
  return css`
    animation: ${duration} ${tmp} ${fillMode};
  `;
};
```

Now you'll just use the `getCardProps` function to the props that CardFinal expects from the `getCardProps`.

```
export default function App() {
  const cardProps = getCardProps({
    style: null,
    weight: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    colorCard: "grey",
    marginCard: "10px"
  });

  return (
    <CardFinal {...cardProps}>
      YO
    </CardFinal>
  );
}
```

[Here's a codesandbox link of where you can try & play around to see how it works.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-snyder-yygfi?file=/src/App.js)
You can also try to un-comment a `// const WarningDiv`, that basically replicates the warnings you've been encountering with just a basic function that returns an empty `styled.div`

Comment: thanks for the reply! one question, but this way you write all this code directly in the App.js file?

Comment: Oh. You don’t need to structure it this way. You can do whatever structure you want! I just added them in a single file for demo purposes.

Comment: thank you very much! i am managing to solve my problem! But I have another doubt...I have a new problem...how can I handle the case where I have to work directly on styled.component? I attach an example file: https://pastebin.com/6T2cSyLV

Comment: Should just be able to pass a prop on the component via the answer above. I would guess that the code in your pastebin should have the same warning you were trying to avoid

Comment: Okay, thank you very much indeed! Thanks to you I understood a lot and I'm solving some problems! Now unfortunately I have another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263878/it-seems-you-are-interpolating-a-keyframe-declaration-hvshe-into-an-untagged-s