# It seems you are interpolating a keyframe declaration (hVshE) into an untagged string

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, css-animations, warnings, styled-components

Good evening everyone, I have an error with the styled-component library that I can't correct:

> Error: It seems you are interpolating a keyframe declaration (hVshE)
> into an untagged string. This was supported in styled-components v3,
> but is not longer supported in v4 as keyframes are now injected
> on-demand. Please wrap your string in the css`` helper which ensures
> the styles are injected correctly. See
> https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css

the error is when I make the assignment:

```
const CardInner = keyframes`
                
                    flex: 1;
                    display: ${Card.display};
                    text-align: ${Card.textAlign};
                    transition: ${duration};
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
            
                    ${
                      Card.checkLimit && Card.checkLimitFlag
                        ? css`
                            animation: ${tmp} ${duration} ${fillMode};
                          `
                        : Card.checkLimit === false && Card.checkLimitFlag
                        ? css`
                            animation: ${tmp1} ${duration} ${fillMode};
                          `
                        : ""
                    }  
                     
  `;
```

how can i solve it?

[Here is the example project](https://codesandbox.io/embed/green-microservice-d3ovw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Hi have you tried passing simply the string ` \`animation: ${tmp} ${duration} ${fillMode};\`` without the call to `css`

Comment: @t3__rry yes, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the tagged template literal to the tag function equivalent.

**Source:** [Not recognising infinity as valid keyword #247](https://github.com/styled-components/stylelint-processor-styled-components/issues/247#issuecomment-525524944)

```js
const fadeIn = keyframes`...`

// EQUIVALENT TO: css`${fadeIn} 0.2s linear;`
const animationRule = css(
  (['', ' 0.2s linear;'] as any) as TemplateStringsArray,
  fadeIn
)

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  animation: ${animationRule}
`
```